# React native doesn't build after link some modules

Tags: react-native

I have linked some modules(react-native-gesture-handler, i18n, react-native-svg) successfully. But after linking some modules for example react-native-maps and react-native-camera react native stops building. And shows me an error like that;

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error: Cannot create directory D:\Work\project\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of output files for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' property 'incrementalFolder' during up-to-date check.
> Could not read path 'D:\Work\project\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BU¦LD FAILED in 0s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug
debug Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\Work\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:58:39)
    at buildAndRun (D:\Work\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:142:41)
    at D:\Work\project\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:104:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

Its really annoying. I was using expo before and everything was working nicely. But now i can't use camera, qr code, maps...

React Native version;

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.8
```

Edit; I have tried linking manuel and automatic.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the error says something pretty clear. Have you checked everything regarding the device/emulator?

Comment: emulator works normally before linking and after unlink the modules. i don't think there is a problem about emulator

Comment: You were using expo before, what are you using now ? Can we see the error above ? ("read the error above for details") Does it work on IOS after linking modules ?

Comment: @hardworker I'm using react-native-cli now. I edited the error message for show all. I cannot test it on IOS because i don't have mac.

Comment: @hardworker its worked for react-native-maps but not for react-native-camera. thank you.

Comment: @CemKocagöz As stated in the log, i don't think the problem come from the module. I might be related to cache or anything else, that's why i flagged as possible duplicate